# how to use interpolation to get value in a model

Tags: javascript, interpolation

I have data in model, I also have a variable which contains value in this model

```
 buildField = ['dataArray'][0]['person']['firstname'].
```

How I can use it with model ? I have tried interpolation

```
 console.log(resultat build ${_model+${buildField}});
```

But that does not work –

_model['dataArray'][0]['person']['firstname'] exist and gives a value

Comment: I think the first quote is wront in your code